# pass modal through a function to a child component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use the idea about the encapsulation and single responsibility principle, so I came up with this idea where I pass the ngb modal to the child component thru a function. But I am running into trouble because the child component does not recognise the `open` method. Here is the code I try to implement the idea I have.

***parent.component.ts***

```
@ViewChild('showModal') showModal: NgbModal;
Menu: { title: string, action: Function, };
...
ngOnInit() {
 let menu: Menu = {
  title: "Hello",
  action: function() {
   this.modalService.open(this.showModal);
  },
 this.menu = menu;
}
```

***parent.component.html***

```
<child [menu]="menu"></child>
..
<ng-template #showModal let-c="close">
 <div class="modal-body">
  HELLO WORLD!!!
 </div>
 <button (click)="c('Close')">Close</button>
</ng-template>
```

***child.component.ts***

```
@Input() menu;
...
handleFunc(menu) {
 if(menu && typeof menu === 'function) {
  menu.action ();
 }
}
```

***child.component.html***

```
<a (click)="handleFunc(menu)">Pop up</a>
```

***Error message***

> **ERROR TypeError**: Cannot read property `open` of `undefined`

How can I get this to work?

Comment: can you  create stackblitz for the same ?

Comment: when you `console.log(menu)` in child component what does it prints ? also try making arrow function for action in parent component. i.e. `action: () => {
   this.modalService.open(this.showModal);
  },`